# Use Solrj in OSGi Container

Tags: java, solr, osgi, solrj, apache-servicemix

I have a jax-rs service that i'm deploying into fuse esb which uses solrj to connect to a solr server. I've added the following maven dependancy to the project:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Standalone testing works fine, connecting to solrj works fine. BUT when i deploy to the osgi container i get a ClassNotFoundException for classes in the org.apache.noggit package. My question is:

what osgi package should i be using for solrj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Fuse ESB then its easier to install using features. You can install solr by

```
features:install camel-solr
```

And you can see all the features available out of the box with

```
features:list
```

Comment: I ended up just wrapping the solrj jar in an osgi bundle with an eclipse plugin project. but your solution is much easier. thanks.